# Excel File Not Showing Up in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a new Google Sheets spreadsheet from a CSV using the API in Python and my code runs but the created Sheet does not show up in my Google Drive anywhere. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

#Set up a credentials object I think
creds =
ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', 
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

#Now build our api object, thing
drive_api = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

folder_id = "1g3q1OelKXDJF8H_Kc0IpgFSxz77NQobc"
file_name = "1505"
mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"

print("Uploading file " + file_name + "...")


file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'mimeType': mimeType
}

#We have to make a request hash to tell the google API what we're giving it
body = {'name': file_name, 'mimeType': mimeType}
body['parents'] = [{'id':folder_id}]

#Now create the media file upload object and tell it what file to upload,
#in this case 'test.html'
media = MediaFileUpload('1505.csv', mimetype = 'text/csv')

#Now we're doing the actual post, creating a new file of the uploaded type
fiahl = drive_api.files().create(body=body, media_body=media).execute()

#Because verbosity is nice
print("Created file '%s' id '%s'." % (fiahl.get('name'), fiahl.get('id')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Issue:

I think that your script works. But from your script, if no error occurs when you run the script and `client_secret.json` is the file when the Service Account is created, I think that you are trying to upload a file using Service Account. Service Account is not your account. So when you upload a file to Google Drive using Service Account, the file is created to the Drive of the Service Account. By this, the uploaded file cannot be seen on your Google Drive.

### Solution

When you want to see the uploaded file using the Service Account at your Google Drive, please share the file with your account. By this, when the file is uploaded using Service Account, you can see the uploaded file

#### Modification point:

- You use Drive API v3. So please modify `body['parents'] = [{'id':folder_id}]` to `body['parents'] = [folder_id]`.
- If the folder ID of `folder_id = "1g3q1OelKXDJF8H_Kc0IpgFSxz77NQobc"` is on your Google Drive, please modify this to the folder ID on Service Account. As a test case, I used `root` as the folder ID.
- After the file is uploaded by the Service account, the owner is changed to your account. By this, you can see the uploaded file at the root of your Google Drive.

#### Modified script:

Before you run the script, please set the email address of your Google account to `'emailAddress': '### Email address of your Google account ###'`.

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# Set up a credentials object I think
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

# Now build our api object, thing
drive_api = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

folder_id = "root"  # Modified from "1g3q1OelKXDJF8H_Kc0IpgFSxz77NQobc"
file_name = "1505"
mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"

print("Uploading file " + file_name + "...")

file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'mimeType': mimeType
}

# We have to make a request hash to tell the google API what we're giving it
body = {'name': file_name, 'mimeType': mimeType}
body['parents'] = [folder_id]  # Modified

# Now create the media file upload object and tell it what file to upload,
# in this case 'test.html'
media = MediaFileUpload('1505.csv', mimetype='text/csv')

# Now we're doing the actual post, creating a new file of the uploaded type
fiahl = drive_api.files().create(body=body, media_body=media).execute()

# Because verbosity is nice
print("Created file '%s' id '%s'." % (fiahl.get('name'), fiahl.get('id')))

# I added below script.
user_permission = {
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'owner',
    'emailAddress': '### Email address of your Google account ###'
}
drive_api.permissions().create(
    fileId=fiahl.get('id'),
    body=user_permission,
    transferOwnership=True,
).execute()
```

### Note:

- In this case, you cannot put the file to the specific folder of your Google Account. Because the Service Account is used.

  - **If you want to directly upload the file to the specific folder on your Google Drive, please use OAuth2 instead of Service account.**
- This is a simple modified script. So please modify this for your situation.

### References:

- [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts?hl=en)
- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is exaclty the answer I needed, thanks so much!

Comment: @Emnut Oggionni Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.